# Hide ListBox of Combo Dropdown (made with fluent ui, fluent-select)

Tags: html, typescript, dynamics-crm, fluent-ui

I get a combo dropdown with fluent ui like this:

HTML:

```
<th class="dropdown-analytic">
     <fluent-select title="x" id="dropdown" onchange="x()"></fluent-select>
</th>
```

Typescript:

let dropdown = document.getElementById('dropdown');

{
let fluentOption = document.createElement("fluent-option");

```
fluentOption.setAttribute('value', X;

fluentOption.innerText = X;

dropdown.appendChild(fluentOption);
```

}

I need to hide the ListBox of the combo dropdown when there's only 1 option to choose. I mean, the list of fluent-options shouldn't be displayed.

When the for = 1, hide listbox. How can I do that with code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED:

dropdown.listbox.style.visibility = "hidden";